# Не могу преобразовать содержимое файла в integer на php

Tags: php

Cегодня пытался сделать свой счетчик посещений на сайт **(php)**.

Задача была сделать счетчик и его исходный код максимально простым , вот алгоритм:

- Пользователь заходит на страницу сайта
- скрипт берет предыдущее значение количества посещений страницы из файла (count.txt)
- преобразует строку файла в integer
- прибавляет +1
- стирает предыдущее значение из файла и записывает новое
- выводит новое значение на экран (не через `echo` , а непосредственно способом html через тег `<p>`)

Вот кусок кода, который я смог написать :

```
<?php
$count = file_get_contents('count.txt');
$countInt = (int) $count;
$countInt = $countInt++;
file_put_contents('count.txt', $countInt);
?>
```

К сожалению, из рабочего тут только чтение из файла в переменную. Подскажите пожалуйста , что именно тут надо изменить/добавить , чтобы код соответствовал описанному алгоритму выше?

Comment: А в чем именно затруднение с выполнением последнего пункта?

Comment: Собственно ни в чем, просто кусок кода, ответственный за вывод находится вне скрипта php, поэтому я его и не включил в код, предоставленный здесь.